# Como montar um XSD apartir da consulta wsdl?

Tags: web-service, xml, wsdl, xsd

Objetivo: montar o XSD em blocos no eclipse da consulta ao webservice abaixo:
https://valadares.sigiss.com.br/valadares/ws/sigiss_ws.php?wsdl
é gerado o XML:

```
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:sigiss_ws" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:sigiss_ws">
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:sigiss_ws">
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
<xsd:complexType name="tcDescricaoRps">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="ccm" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cnpj" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="senha" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="crc" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="crc_estado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="aliquota_simples" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="id_sis_legado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="servico" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="situacao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="valor" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="base" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="descricaoNF" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_tipo" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_cnpj" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_email" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_ie" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_im" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_razao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_fantasia" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_endereco" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_numero" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_complemento" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_bairro" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_CEP" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_cod_cidade" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_fone" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_ramal" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tomador_fax" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="rps_num" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="rps_serie" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="rps_dia" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="rps_mes" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="rps_ano" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="outro_municipio" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cod_outro_municipio" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="retencao_iss" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="pis" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cofins" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="inss" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="irrf" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="csll" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="tipo_obra" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="dia_emissao" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="mes_emissao" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="ano_emissao" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcLoteRps">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:tcDescricaoRps[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcRetornoNota">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="Resultado" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="Nota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="LinkImpressao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="autenticidade" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcEstruturaDescricaoErros">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="DescricaoProcesso" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="DescricaoErro" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcDescricaoErros">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:tcEstruturaDescricaoErros[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcDadosPrestador">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="ccm" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cnpj" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="senha" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="crc" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="crc_estado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="aliquota_simples" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcDadosCancelaNota">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="ccm" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cnpj" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="senha" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="nota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="motivo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcNotas">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:int[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcDadosNota">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="nota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="id_sis_legado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="autenticidade" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="dt_conversao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="num_rps" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="serie_rps" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="emissao_rps" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_razao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_endereco" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_numero" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_complemento" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_bairro" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_cidade" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_estado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_cep" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_email" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="valor" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="base" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="servico" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="aliquota_atividade" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="iss" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cnpj_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="razao_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="endereco_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="numero_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="complemento_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="bairro_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cidade_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="estado_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="cep_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="email_tomador" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="descricao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="ISSRetido" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="StatusNFe" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="situacao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="OpcaoSimples" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="LinkImpressao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcConsultaFaixaNota">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="mesI" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="mesF" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="anoI" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="anoF" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcDadosConsultaNota">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="nota" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="serie" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="valor" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_ccm" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="prestador_cnpj" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="autenticidade" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="tcListaDadosNota">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:tcDadosNota[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="GerarNotaRequest">
<part name="DescricaoRps" type="tns:tcDescricaoRps"/>
</message>
<message name="GerarNotaResponse">
<part name="RetornoNota" type="tns:tcRetornoNota"/>
<part name="DescricaoErros" type="tns:tcDescricaoErros"/>
</message>
<message name="CancelarNotaRequest">
<part name="DadosCancelaNota" type="tns:tcDadosCancelaNota"/>
</message>
<message name="CancelarNotaResponse">
<part name="RetornoNota" type="tns:tcRetornoNota"/>
<part name="DescricaoErros" type="tns:tcDescricaoErros"/>
</message>
<message name="ConsultarNotaValidaRequest">
<part name="DadosConsultaNota" type="tns:tcDadosConsultaNota"/>
</message>
<message name="ConsultarNotaValidaResponse">
<part name="RetornoNota" type="tns:tcRetornoNota"/>
<part name="DescricaoErros" type="tns:tcDescricaoErros"/>
</message>
<message name="ConsultarNotaPrestadorRequest">
<part name="DadosPrestador" type="tns:tcDadosPrestador"/>
<part name="Nota" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="ConsultarNotaPrestadorResponse">
<part name="DadosNota" type="tns:tcDadosNota"/>
<part name="DescricaoErros" type="tns:tcDescricaoErros"/>
</message>
<message name="geratesteRequest">
<part name="dado" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="geratesteResponse">
<part name="retorno" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="WebService SigISSPortType">
<operation name="GerarNota">
<documentation>Gera a nota fiscal eletrônica</documentation>
<input message="tns:GerarNotaRequest"/>
<output message="tns:GerarNotaResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="CancelarNota">
<documentation>Faz o cancelamento da nota fiscal eletrônica</documentation>
<input message="tns:CancelarNotaRequest"/>
<output message="tns:CancelarNotaResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="ConsultarNotaValida">
<documentation>
Faz a consulta de uma nota fiscal eletrônica para saber se esta válida
</documentation>
<input message="tns:ConsultarNotaValidaRequest"/>
<output message="tns:ConsultarNotaValidaResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="ConsultarNotaPrestador">
<documentation>Faz a consulta de uma nota fiscal eletrônica</documentation>
<input message="tns:ConsultarNotaPrestadorRequest"/>
<output message="tns:ConsultarNotaPrestadorResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="gerateste">
<documentation>1 - retorna Hello World</documentation>
<input message="tns:geratesteRequest"/>
<output message="tns:geratesteResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="WebService SigISSBinding" type="tns:WebService SigISSPortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="GerarNota">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:sigiss_ws#GerarNota" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="CancelarNota">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:sigiss_ws#CancelarNota" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="ConsultarNotaValida">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:sigiss_ws#ConsultarNotaValida" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="ConsultarNotaPrestador">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:sigiss_ws#ConsultarNotaPrestador" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="gerateste">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:sigiss_ws#gerateste" style="rpc"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:sigiss_ws" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="WebService SigISS">
<port name="WebService SigISSPort" binding="tns:WebService SigISSBinding">
<soap:address location="https://valadares.sigiss.com.br:443/valadares/ws/sigiss_ws.php"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**Objetivo**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De que forma posso montar o XSD para ser visualizado no eclipse ?